# Split a String on 2nd last occurrence of comma in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, split

I have a string say

```
var str = "xy,yz,zx,ab,bc,cd";
```

and I want to split it on the 2nd last occurrence of a comma in C# i.e

```
a = "xy,yz,zx,ab"
b = "bc,cd"
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: You could use LINQ's skip and take

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's find the required comma `index` with a help of `LastIndexOf`:

```
  var str = "xy,yz,zx,ab,bc,cd";

  // index of the 2nd last occurrence of ','
  int index = str.LastIndexOf(',', str.LastIndexOf(',') - 1);
```

Then use `Substring`:

```
  string a = str.Substring(0, index);
  string b = str.Substring(index + 1);
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.WriteLine(a);
  Comsole.WriteLine(b);
```

Outcome:

```
  xy,yz,zx,ab
  bc,cd
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative "readable" approach ;)

```
const string text = "xy,yz,zx,ab,bc,cd";

var words = text.Split(',');
var firstBatch = Math.Max(words.Length - 2, 0);

var first = string.Join(",", words.Take(firstBatch));
var second = string.Join(",", words.Skip(firstBatch));

first.Should().Be("xy,yz,zx,ab"); // Pass OK
second.Should().Be("bc,cd");      // Pass OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this via regex replacement:

```
var str = "xy,yz,zx,ab,bc,cd";
var a = Regex.Replace(str, @",[^,]+,[^,]+$", "");
var b = Regex.Replace(str, @"^.*,([^,]+,[^,]+)$", "$1");
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

This prints:

```
xy,yz,zx,ab
bc,cd
```

Answer (score 0):

It you get Microsoft's System.Interactive extensions from NuGet then you can do this:

```
string output = String.Join(",", str.Split(',').TakeLast(2));
```